# Subset a table by whether two columns fall within any reference range in a lookup table in R

Tags: r, range, subset

R Table1: In reality many more rows

```
PatientID chr pos  type end  length 
AB1       1  2431  DEL 2100  -331
AC3       1  98041 INV 99100  1059
AG6       1  8743  BND 9000   257
```

Table 2: In reality many more rows, columns 2 and 3 are the ranges for the exon

```
Exon 2001 2500 
Exon 8700 8750
```

Desired output: Those rows from table 1 where any part of the variants (from pos-end) fall within anywhere of the range of an Exon in table2

output:

```
PatientID chr pos  type end   length 
AB1       1  2431  DEL 2100  -331
AG6       1  8743  BND 9000   257
```

I have tried a subset:

```
subset(table1$pos >= table2$V2 | table1$end <= table$end)
```

but this does not give me my desired output. Any help would be much appreciated.

All the best

Comment: I think you want `&&` and, rather than `|`, to drive subset to the 'is it between these?' for a given Exon range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find variants which (for at least one range in table2, *r*) meet at least one of the following conditions:

1. `table1$end` is within *r*
2. `table1$pos` is within *r*
3. `table1$pos` and `table2$end` are on opposite sides of *r*

Below are schematic depictions of all possibilities with *r* delimited by brackets and a variant represented by hyphens together with the numbers of conditions met.

```
-[-  ]   1.
 [  -]-  2.
 [ - ]   1. and 2.
-[---]-  3.
```

Please note that the code below assumes that (unlike table1) `table2[, 2]` <= `table2[, 3]`.

```r
# simplified table1
table1 <- data.frame(pos=c(2431, 98041, 8743), end=c(2100, 99100, 9000))
table2 <- data.frame(exon='Exon', from=c(2001, 8700), to=c(2500, 8750))

is.within <- apply(table1[, c('pos', 'end')], 1, function(x) {
  
  x <- sort(x)  # make sure x[1] <= x[2], i.e. pos <= end
  any((x[1] >= table2[, 2] & x[1] <= table2[, 3]) |      # 1.
        (x[2] >= table2[, 2] & x[2] <= table2[, 3]) |    # 2.
        (x[1] <= table2[, 2] & x[2] >= table2[, 3]))     # 3.
        
})
table1[is.within, ]
```

Comment: Dear Robert, many thanks that is correct yes. Table 1 represents a single stretch of DNA that has been deleted, inverted or some other large alteration. I want to see if that crosses or involves an "exon" in any capacity, from a biological perpspective there are millions of variants so picking out the ones that cross an exon(which affects protein function) is important, I am trying to get signal from noise. Your code worked wonderfully thanks.